# Image filter speed too slow compare with instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagefilter

I am using the source code : [Filtrr](https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr) to do the image effects.

But I had face a serious problem for the loading speed between every image is very slow.

I try to compare with Instagram app, it look like almost don't have any loading.
Is that any one can show me the way can reduce the loading speed? thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried Aviary SDK http://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios?

Comment: Or [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)? GPUImage will probably be the fastest solution and it is completely open source with tons of sample code out there (including in the main repo).

Comment: i know i cant base on Instagram to the standard, but at least i trying to hope can find a solution to reduce the loading speed.